# Prove that $\frac{x^3}{x^2+y} + \frac{y^3}{y^2+z} + \frac{z^3}{z^2+x} \ge \frac{3}{2}$

Tags: inequality

With $x,y,z \gt 0$ and $x+y+z=3$, prove $\frac{x^3}{x^2+y} + \frac{y^3}{y^2+z} + \frac{z^3}{z^2+x} \ge \frac{3}{2}$.

I tried many method from AM-GM but it doesn't work for me. I hope you guys can solve the problem or at least give me a hint so that I could know how to do the same type of problem next time.

Answer (score 3):

By AM-GM, we have
$$\frac{x^3}{x^2 + y} - x = - \frac{xy}{x^2 + y} \ge - \frac{xy}{2\sqrt{x^2 \cdot y}} = -\frac12 \sqrt{y} \ge - \frac12 \cdot \frac{1 + y}{2}.$$
Thus, we have
$$\frac{x^3}{x^2+y} + \frac{y^3}{y^2+z} + \frac{z^3}{z^2+x}
\ge x + y + z - \frac{1 + y + 1 + z + 1 + x}{4} = \frac32.$$
We are done.